# Create deep list with non unique key

Tags: java, arrays, list, dictionary

I have created the following list but at the first definition I use **hash map**(for the first string) but now i **don't want it to be unique**,how should i define it?

```
HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> entityList = new HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>();
```

Since the hash map is defined here I can enter to the main list duplicate entries,
how should i change my definition that can give my the option to enter duplicated entry.

I need to build it like the following structure.

```
emp<name,test>
   <lastname,lastname>
   <salery,1000> 
emp<firstname,dan>
   <age,20>
adress<post,111>
      <street,hhh>
```

Comment: unable to comprehend anything! (O_o)

Comment: I have edit my post ,sorry...\

Comment: Its still vague. What exactly is your requirement?

Comment: If you use HashMap, and call get("emp"), what do you expect to get?

Comment: I can't quite understand why you'd want the ambiguity you'd introduce by doing this in your data structure - surely it would be better to separate them out into separate data structures? How exactly are you planning on extracting the data again later elegantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using hashmap requires the keys to be unique, otherwise - how can you get the correct value???

What you can do is relate several values to a single key, using `HashMap<String, List<valueType>>`

You can use:

```
HashMap<String, List<yourObject>>
```

So every key has several objects related to.

In your case:

```
HashMap<String, List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>>
```

If you need a collection with multiple objects, you can use `List<yourObject>` and `yourObject` will be just as you want (hold a `String` and `LinkedHashMap<String, String>` in your example).

I would use the first choice, but if you really dont want it - use the `List<yourObject>`

Comment: I have edit my post,so your solution is not valid ...

Comment: I think it is valid. Here you can store several values per key => key is not unique.

Comment: Its still pretty unclear. What duplicate entries you want to add? and what is your "main list" in  "I can enter to the main list duplicate entries"?

Comment: like the emp in my example, i can add many entries of emp with different list that related to it

Comment: OK. so if you call get("emp"), what do you expect to get? Maybe a list of relevant values?

Comment: I dont need to call get(emp) i just need to build it and latter on loop on it

Comment: But if later you will? or someone else will? I really dont understand why you think my answer doesn't fit you.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want is like, same unique key- many value.
But any Map definition Key is unique by default. Because every Map perform any operation with respect to it key. 
So it's better to use different structure for your application. you can Try like this..

> `HashMap <String, Object> entityList = new HashMap<String, Object>();`
>   `LinkedHashMap<String, String> linkedHashmap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();`
>   `entityList.put("key1", updateObject(entityList.get("key1", newkey, new value);`
>   `public LinkedHashMap<
>   String, String> updateObject(LinkedHashMap<String, String> linkedHashmap,String newKey,String newValue){`
>   `linkedHashmap.put(newKey,newValue);`
>   `return linkedHashmap;`
>   `}`

Comment: I don't see how you can recommend a specific implementation without questioning the original poster's motives. Why did he choose HashMap? How does he need to deal with the potentially many associated values? These questions must be answered before an adequate implementation can be recommended.

Comment: Thanks @ClassStacker for helping me(How to recommend an answer).
As the Original poster started implementing HashMap and and for same key user want to store different types of data, thus I suggest HashMap with Object as value.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can take a look at [`Guava MultiMap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

> **`public interface Multimap<K,V>`**
>
> A collection similar to a Map, but which may associate multiple values
>   with a single key. If you call `put(K, V)` twice, with the same key but
>   different values, the multimap contains mappings from the key to both
>   values.